# Get all task information via API from asana

Tags: api, asana

i'm writing a simple application to build a task dependency tree (i declare a dependency by commenting on a task "Depend on: ") using asana API, it is indeed a simple task and should also be a simple and quick script, but i got to a bottle neck here.

From the API documentation i get that i need to:
Query the project tasks using /project//tasks
iterate trough tasks to:

- get complete task information, since i'm only getting id and name.
- Get task stories.

what i would like to do is a simple api call to get all this information at once, like:
/project//tasks options.expand {task, stories}. Am i missing something or this it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Complete information about tasks you can get with one request thanks to "opt_fields" option (https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options).

Unfortunately "stories" still need another request.

Answer (score 0):

No. As seen in the asana queries are tree-like structure. To get the story you require workspace_id > project_id > task_id & task_id for story. I recommend that you use a loop. Tasks of the project for getting information on the tasks and history. Upon receipt of the task id - send two requests info task & stories. Thank you, Ruslan.